# Matching data in a file to user input data using int (java)

Tags: java, io, int, compare

I need to scan the examdata.txt file and find where an int in the file matches the int input by the user. The file I'm reading contains entries as:

ACCY111 CO216   10  20  ABD ALSOP
ACCY111 CO228   10  16  AMBALAWANAR AVES
ACCY111 EALT006 10  72  AYSON   CHALMERS
ACCY111 GBLT1   10  72  CHAN    DENG
ACCY111 GBLT2   10  72  DES GARDEN

where the third entry is the date i want to use.

This is my code:

```
    public void printSession(int targetDate)
{

try
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("examdata.txt"));
    while (scan.hasNext())
    {
        if (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            int date = scan.nextInt();
            if (date == targetDate)
            {
                UI.println(scan.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (IOException e)
{
    UI.println("File read error." + e);
}
}
```

It outputs nothing.. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Where am I going wrong?

For your code to consume any input, both `scan.hasNext()` and `scan.hasNextInt()` must be true. However, given that the very first character of the file is a letter, the code will never get past it.

Comment: but shouldn't `scan.hasNext()` keep evaluating until the next token is an int?

Comment: @JakeBarnby: No, it keeps looking at the same token over and over again. You need to call `scan.nextXXX()` to advance.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much. I added `scan.next()` as the first command in the while loop and now I am at least seeing results. But it only prints the tokens _after_ the evaluation is correct. How can I make it print the whole line excluding the date?

For example if `targetDate` = 10 for the line 
ACCY111 CO216 10 20 ABD ALSOP would only print 20 ABD ALSOP.
I want to print:
ACCY111 CO216 20 ABD ALSOP